# Detecting Color of Pixel Where Tapped in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, writeablebitmap

There is an image in "Image" control. When user taps image control, the color should be extracted of that exact pixel.

This is the code provided by msdn, for **Windows Phone 8**. [In Chroma Key Demo For Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn859579.aspx)

```
private async void ViewfinderCanvas_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var point = e.GetPosition(ViewfinderCanvas);
    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)ViewfinderCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)ViewfinderCanvas.ActualHeight);

    using (var source = new CameraPreviewImageSource(App.Camera))
    using (var effect = new FilterEffect(source))
    using (var renderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(effect, bitmap, OutputOption.Stretch))
    {
        effect.Filters = new List<IFilter>()
        {
            new RotationFilter(_rotationFilter.RotationAngle)
        };

        await renderer.RenderAsync();

        var picked = bitmap.Pixels[((int)point.Y) * bitmap.PixelWidth + ((int)point.X)];

        _color = new Color
        {
            A = 0xFF,
            R = (byte)((picked & 0x00FF0000) >> 16),
            G = (byte)((picked & 0x0000FF00) >> 8),
            B = (byte)(picked & 0x000000FF)
        };
    }

    ColorBorder.Background = new SolidColorBrush(_color);
}
```

My edited code,

```
private void FilteredView_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       var Point = e.GetPosition(FilteredView);

       var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)FilteredView.ActualWidth, (int)FilteredView.ActualHeight);





        // ERROR HERE
           var picked = bitmap.Pixels[((int)Point.Y) * bitmap.PixelWidth + ((int)Point.X)];

           _color = new Color
           {
               A = 0xFF,
               R = (byte)((picked & 0x00FF0000) >> 16),
               G = (byte)((picked & 0x0000FF00) >> 8),
               B = (byte)(picked & 0x000000FF)
           };



   }
```

FilteredView is Image Control. I just need the color at pointer, so I dont use filters etc because it is not of any use here. Also function does not need to be async.

Error says,  'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' does not contain a definition for 'Pixels'.

Project template is Windows Phone 8.1 project.

Lumia Imaging SDK is imported (mentioned if any the Bitmap types are conflicting).

**Question**: Is this even the right way to do it? If yes then what is possible alternate for using a WriteableBitmap class to access pixels?